# Alterar formulário antes de submetê-lo

Tags: symfony-2

Existem 2 entidades: Client e Apps.

A associação entre cliente e app é feita na entidade `Client` da seguinte maneira:

```
class Clients {

    /**
    * App id
    *
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Apps", inversedBy="clients", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
    * @JoinColumn(name="app_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Código da aplicação inválido.")
    */
    private $appId;

    //...
}
```

O problema é que não quero expor nenhum `id` no formulário, então cada app além do `id`, possui o campo `reference` e é esse valor que é enviado pelo formulário, veja abaixo o build do form:

```
class ClientType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('reference', TextType::class, [
                'mapped' => false
            ])
            ->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class)
            ->add('lastname', TextType::class)
           ->add('phone', TextType::class)
           ->add('email', EmailType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Clients',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }
}
```

Repare que o campo `reference` é falso, ou seja, ele não existe na minha entidade e sim o campo `appId`.

Ao salvar o meu form, o campo `appId` vai com o valor `null` e o seguinte erro de validação ocorre (a mensagem foi definida via annotation no código acima):

> Código da aplicação inválido.

No controller, tenho o seguinte código:

```
//...
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
$client = new Clients();

$form = $this->createForm(ClientType::class, $client);
$form->submit($data);

if ($form->isValid()) {
   //...
}
//...
```

Antes de fazer o submit do formulário, preciso preencher o campo `appId` com um `id` válido de acordo com a referência enviada através do campo `reference`.

Answer (score 0):

Quando me deparo com problemas em que não posso expor valores nos formulários da minha aplicação, o que eu faço é simplesmente preencher esses valores após o formulário submetido ter sido validado.

Então o código ficaria assim.

Form:

```
class ClientType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class)
            ->add('lastname', TextType::class)
            ->add('phone', TextType::class)
            ->add('email', EmailType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Clients',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(ClientType::class, new Clients());
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $clients = $form->getData();
    $clients->setAppId($appId);
    $this-getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($clients);
    $this-getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. O appId não é genérico, como isso é um endpoint comum a vários formulários, cada um tem o seu ID, por isso essa informação vem do formulário, ou seja, estou a dizer ao sistema que houve um novo registro proveniente do formulário X, por isso estou a utilizar uma referência e não o próprio ID.

Comment: Entretanto resolvi o problema mantendo o campo "reference" com a propriedade "mapped" igual a "false" e no controlador faço um "find" com o valor preenchido,  verifico se o valor é verdadeiro e então faço o set do ID da app conforme a sua resposta.